# Stringification char '#' using c/c++ macro on arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk, macros

I have a macro like this.

```
#define TO_STR(x) #x
```

I can use this macro to make string without the input string between char `"`  .
Like :

```
const char* test = TO_STR(hello,macro);
std::cout << test << std::endl;
```

I can got :
    `hello,macro` correctly .

My question is : how can I deal with char `#` in the input string .
Like :

```
const char* shaderprogram = TO_STR(#version 300 es \n);
```

This will cause an error , any suggestion ?

Comment: *"This will cause an error"* - what error do you see?  Works as I'd expect [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/476b8c47689d378d)....

Comment: If `TO_STR` is really `#define`'d like this, then `TO_STR(hello,macro)` should be ill-formed....

Comment: @TonyD Thanks for your reply ,  I got `error: invalid preprocessing directive #version`  .

Comment: Are you really using gcc?

Comment: @rici Thanks for you reply , my compiler should called ”arm-linux-androideabi-gcc“　, my bad , I will correct it .

Comment: @cpplearner Yes, Thanks for you point it out, my bad , I should change an example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is illformed, since the preprocessor will treat the `,` as separating two arguments, not as part of an argument.

You could try creating a second macro

```
#define TO_STR2(a,b) TO_STR(a) "," TO_STR(b)
```

If you then want to do the same with three arguments, you would need to define another macro

```
#define TO_STR3(a,b,c) TO_STR2(a,b) "," TO_STR(c)
```

which is possible for more arguments, but messy - after all, macros aren't really intended to be used for this sort of thing.

The solution to the second is easy

```
const char* shaderprogram = "#" TO_STR(version 300 es \n);
```

The real solution, however, is to get away from any obsession of having a macro that allows you to leave the `"` characters off string literals.   Only use the stringizing operator in a macro when it is the ONLY solution to the problem, not as the first tool of choice when there are alternatives.

After all, this

```
const char* shaderprogram = "#" TO_STR(version 300 es \n);   // blech!
```

is inferior to

```
const char* shaderprogram = "#version 300 es \n";
```

by several measures - including readability, maintainability, etc etc

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I should change an example , the `,` is my mistake , it should be `const char* test = TO_STR(hello123);` , but you had point it out , This should help to the others who has ill-formed macro question  .   You have solution for my real question . It works . We just have to take care of the first char `#` , other macro which after any char is no problem. Thanks again .